# How to programmatically issue a mouse click on a page

Tags: java, html, javafx

I just run my first application with [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) like this:

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load("http://localhost:8080/my/page.jsp");
```

Is it possible with javafx to programmatically click over the opened page with X and Y coordinates in regard to WindView view?

Answer (score 1):

javaFx does not have a nice way of generating mouse events yet

but you can use java.awt.Robot

```
try{
  Robot robby = new Robot();
//move mouse to location to click
  robby.mouseMove(1000, 550); 
// and click
  robby.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  robby.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}catch (AWTException ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HTMLInputElement x = (HTMLInputElement) webEngine.getDocument().getElementsByTagName("input").item(0);
```

That returns a **org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLInputElement** instance which has the .click() method built in... which "simulates a click".

This will allow you to simulate the click.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 adds an ability to [construct a MouseEvent](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MouseEvent%28java.lang.Object,%20javafx.event.EventTarget,%20javafx.event.EventType,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20javafx.scene.input.MouseButton,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20javafx.scene.input.PickResult%29) that you can dispatch via an [EventDispatcher](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/event/EventDispatcher.html) or [fire on a Window](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/stage/Window.html#fireEvent%28javafx.event.Event%29).